# How to use an existing google spreadsheet (with formulas and formatting) as a template in the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have built a spreadsheet for project management purposes. It contains a WBS Template tab which is blank but has all the formatting and the formulas. I have also added some custom menus which are as follows: New Project >> Create a new project.

Now when a user clicks on to create a new project (from the custom menu), the WBS template should automatically appear (in a new sheet, called "All Projects") and the user should fill in the details with all the formatting and formulas in place.

Again, when a new project is being created, the user should click on "create new project" and the template should appear now in a new row of the "All Projects" tab.

This is a major project for me, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo
Here you can you  API to copy one sheet to another with all data. Where your template will the source file.

Comment: Thank you, is there any code which I can use for this? I am not familiar with API so unsure how it works.

Comment: Which language do you work with?

Comment: Can you share the code you are using as well as giving more details on what exactly is not working as expected? Moreover, are you receiving any errors?